# Full screen switch in ProcessFlow control SAPUI5

Tags: sap-fiori, sapui5

The [UX guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/process-flow/#components) for `sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlow` mentions of a header toolbar, with the possibility of a 'Full screen' toggle for the entire ProcessFlow control, apart from 'Zoom In', 'Zoom Out' etc. (see top right in the image).
However, the API doesn't have any aggregations to add neither the toggle nor any toolbar.

Is it possible to add a Full screen toggle to ProcessFlow control?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that these controls(or toolbar) are not part of [Process Flow](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlow.html) UI5 Control.

These buttons are places in the header content of [`sap.m.Page`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Page.html).

Nevertheless, [`sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlow`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlow.html) provides [`zoomIn()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlow.html#zoomIn) and [`zoomOut()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.suite.ui.commons.ProcessFlow.html#zoomOut) methods.

And coming to `FullScreen` thing, you can use [`sap.m.SplitApp`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitAppMode.html) with [`mode`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitAppMode.html) as `HideMode`.

[You can try Combinations here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.SplitApp/preview)

> P.S: Don't always go with screenshots. They could be jazzy and for demo purpose only.

*Disclaimer: All opinions are personal. I don't talk on behalf of any employer.*